# PHP IMAP_SEARCH exchange email address

Tags: php, email, imap

HI I am trying to search Exchange mail box however when I use

```
$emails = imap_search($connection,'FROM "test@test.com"');
```

I get no message ID back from there server is there away to get round this?

(exchange 2013)

however if I search using TEXT I get the message however it takes ages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to give this a go... at the bottom by dataskills

[Imap_search very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320814/imap-search-very-slow)